# Quando um atributo deve ser uma tabela ou vice versa?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, atributos

Exemplo:
Tenho uma tabela Pedidos, o pedido tem alguns status, novo, entregue, cancelado etc. Quando o status é cancelado eu vou dar a opção do usuário dizer o motivo que foi cancelado, esse motivo deve ser um atributo da tabela pedidos ou deve ser uma tabela a parte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta de sempre: depende. A sua pergunta é basicamente sobre normalização: se você quer manter o seu banco de dados normalizado, pode ser que usar uma tabela extra seja interessante. Mas nem sempre. Vamos por partes:

#### Quais os possíveis valores do motivo de cancelamento?

Se o usuário só pode escolher entre uma lista de opções pré-determinadas (i.e., ele(a) não pode entrar um motivo arbitrário), então para manter a tabela normalizada (eliminando redundâncias, facilitando a atualização desses valores no futuro) você criaria uma nova tabela com os possíveis motivos de cancelamento, e teria uma chave estrangeira na tabela de pedidos "apontando" para essa nova tabela.

Se o usuário pode entrar com motivos arbitrários - por exemplo, o campo a ser preenchido é um campo de texto, ou há uma seleção de motivos com a opção de "outro" onde o usuário pode entrar um texto qualquer - então você não vai ganhar muito em normalizar a tabela, já que potencialmente todos os motivos serão distintos.

#### Como você vai usar esta informação?

A normalização não é uma panaceia que funciona para todas as situações. Por exemplo, se você vai ter muito mais operações de escrita que de leitura que precisem saber do motivo, denormalizar a tabela (i.e., ter o motivo como um campo da tabela dos pedidos) pode fazer mais sentido, mesmo que os motivos potenciais sejam um conjunto pequeno.

#### Outros casos onde a denormalização pode fazer sentido

Um outro caso onde a normalização pode não ser recomendada é se existe a possibilidade de você precisar distribuir as suas tabelas. Se as tabelas precisam ser particionadas (um problema que você provavelmente só terá se tiver trabalhando com um banco de dados de alta escala, ou se ele precisar por algum outro motivo ser geograficamente distribuído), os ganhos de armazenamento e concisão da normalização não compensariam o ganho dos JOINs de partições múltiplas.

Comment: Haveriam alguns motivos fixos e uma opção para outro que aí pode ser inserido pelo usuário

Comment: Se você imagina que a maioria dos usuários escolherão uma das opções padrão, então você pode ter um ganho em criar uma tabela extra (mesmo que nesta tabela você precise armazenar os "outros" motivos do usuário). Como sempre, depende :)

Answer (score 2):

Depende de como você queira manipular esse dado posteriormente. Se esse motivo for apenas para ser registrado, então faz uma coluna ai na tua tabela e armazena ele. Agora se depois você precisar manipular esses dados, até mesmo os status dos pedidos, pode ser interessante criar uma nova tabela. Depende muito do que você vai querer, e também da complexidade.

Comment: O status já é uma tabela a parte porque eu preciso manipular, o motivo é só para guardar mesmo..